# Components not unmounting during conflicting Stack and Drawer navigations - React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

*Sorry, this is going to be long.*

My app is so structured post Login.

```
 - Drawer -->
 -     Dashboard Stack
 -     Project Stack -->
 -         ProjectsList
 -         TablesList
 -         RecordsList
 -     About Stack
```

The Project Stack is as follows -->
 - ProjectsList
 - TablesList (every project has some tables)
 - RecordsList (every table has some records)

The list of these Projects and their tables and consequently their records are highly dynamic and are fetched via the API.

The implementation of my Drawer Component is done by a Custom Component, which comprises of following elements.

[image: Drawer Component]

The implementation of my redirection function on pressing these TouchableOpacity is -->

```
const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
    routeName: route,
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
```

So, one can either go to the RecordsList by -->

1. clicking on Workspaces List --> selecting a project there --> selecting a table from the project;
2. or by clicking on a Project --> selecting a table from the project;

Now, the dashboard also contains widgets. (clicking on which, we can go directly to the recordsList.
Whenever I go directly to the recordsList, it works. But then when I go to another project via the Drawer, my recordsList does not unmount.

Hence, when I receive different props (for a different table), my business logic fails as the componentDidMount and other lifecycle functions aren't invoked.

Thereby, my problem being that when I switch from Stack A's screen(X) to Stack B's screen(Y) and then again to Stack B's different screen (Z). (The screen Y does not unmount).

Also attaching some screenshots.

[image: Dashboard Screen]

[image: Tables List]

[image: Records List]